# I can't save received photo from telegram bot to database like byte array

Tags: spring-boot, telegram-bot

I am trying to save received photo to byte array from telegram bot and store in database.

My code :

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    this.responseText = "Kerakli bo'limni tanlang:";

    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasPhoto()) {
        
        this.chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();

        List<org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.PhotoSize> photo = update.getMessage().getPhoto();

        GetFile getFile = new GetFile();

        getFile.setFileId(update.getMessage().getPhoto().get(0).getFileId());

        File file = getFileRequest(getFile);

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You write that you can't save a photo, but the code snippet does not even have any code that show what you tried. Please show what you tried and tell us the result of it (error messages?). Please also read [ask] to get a an idea about asking better questions.

Comment: I can not get byte array from received photo

Comment: I used to get it many solves I know but I couldn't. There were many codes. Because I didn't write the code. If you know please write it and i will try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633091/telegram-bot-java-library-downloaded-image-quality i wrote it but couldn't get

Comment: @ShahzodbekPulatbekov C# or Java ?

Comment: @HarshadRaval java (I'm writing on spring boot)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, but you can use [getFile](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile) method for this.

Comment: @HarshadRaval how this is done in C#. May be it helps me

Answer (score 0):

When you receives an Update, it contains photo object with `file_id`. Use that file_id to locate `file_path`.

Updates may or may not contain `file_path` or empty `file_path`. So, you need to get that first.

Use `getFile` to get file file information as below. For example, file_id is `AgACAgUAAxkBAAIC`

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string result = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.telegram.org/<botToken>/getFile?file_id=AgACAgUAAxkBAAIC");
```

On calling above code, you will get result something like this:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"file_id":"AgACAgUAAxkBAAIC","file_unique_id":"AQADWaw","file_size":1266,"file_path":"photos/file_0.jpg"}}
```

Now, pass this `file_path` as shown below to convert it to byte array:

```
webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData("https://api.telegram.org/file/<botToken>/photos/file_0.jpg");
```

This is an example in C# using WebClient. I have not used any telegram bot library here. It is just for your help as you requested.